# Content and Experience Editor custom buttons - only show for certain roles

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, security

I've added a couple of custom buttons on the Publish Chunks of the Content and Experience Editors Publish Strips. Right now, these custom buttons show for everyone, but I only want them to show up for certain roles, let's say "RoleA" for clarity.

I thought this could be done by only allowing read access on the button for users with the "RoleA" role assigned to them. However, when I log in with a test user that doesn't have this role (nor is an administrator), the button is still visible and clickable.

How do set it up so that this button is only visible for users with RoleA and Administrators?

I'm working with Sitecore 9.0.1 at the moment.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the rules are defined on the items?

Comment: @MichaelWest see revision for screenshot of my security setting for the Button item.

Comment: @FrankRosario have you provided read access to "Publish" item as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Read` access is inherited by default.

You need to stop inheritance of it for `Sitecore Client Users` first and then add `Read` access for your custom role:

[image]

[image]